# Sbt build .war with custom configuration/profile

Tags: scala, sbt, war, xsbt-web-plugin

I have an sbt project with custom env configuration.

```
  val Prod  = config("prod")  extend Compile describedAs "Scope to build production packages."
  val Stage = config("stage") extend Compile describedAs "Scope to build stage packages."
  val Local = config("local") extend Compile describedAs "Scope to build local packages."

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .configs(Prod, Stage, Local)
  .enablePlugins(WarPlugin)
  .settings(
    name := "pet",
    dependencySettings
  ).
  settings(inConfig(Prod)(Classpaths.configSettings ++ 
Defaults.configTasks ++ Defaults.resourceConfigPaths ++ Seq(
    unmanagedResourceDirectories += {baseDirectory.value / "src" / "main" / configuration.value.name / "resources"}
  )): _*).
  settings(inConfig(Stage)(Classpaths.configSettings ++ 
Defaults.configTasks ++ Defaults.resourceConfigPaths ++ Seq(
    unmanagedResourceDirectories += {baseDirectory.value / "src" / "main" / configuration.value.name / "resources"}
  )): _*).
  settings(inConfig(Local)(Classpaths.configSettings ++ 
Defaults.configTasks ++ Defaults.resourceConfigPaths ++ Seq(
    unmanagedResourceDirectories += {baseDirectory.value / "src" / "main" / configuration.value.name / "resources"}
  )): _*)
```

So when I run `sbt Local/compile` or `sbt Local/run` command I see in the target directory my compiled classes with my Local configuration.

Then I add [xsbt-web-plugin](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin) for packaging `.war` file

```
addSbtPlugin("com.earldouglas" % "xsbt-web-plugin" % "4.2.4")
```

And in `build.sbt`

```
enablePlugins(WarPlugin)
```

Now I try to run `sbt Local/package` command and get just `.jar` but not `.war`

If I run `sbt package` command I get `.jar` and `.war` files but without my Local configuration.

Help me, please. How can I make `sbt Local/package` work correct?
Or maybe you know some other way to build `.war` file with sbt.

Comment: What is the output of `show Local/package` in sbt?

Comment: @earldouglas, 

sbt:pet> show Local/package
[info] C:\Users\Aleksei_Eschenko\Documents\github\pet\target\scala-2.12\pet_2.12-0.1-local.jar
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Dec 10, 2021 5:04:40 PM

Comment: Strange; I would have expected to see a *.war* file there.  Is this part of a multi-module build?  Could the `WarPlugin` seting be applied to a different module from `pet`?

Comment: @earldouglas
It is a single module project. I added code to the question description.

P.S. but in a multi-module project, where I applied `WarPlugin` setting for each separate module for web. I have the same problem.

Comment: It looks like you just need to add the settings manually (rather than having `Project#enablePlugins` do it for you).  Try adding `WarPlugin.projectSettings` to each of the three `inConfig` settings.  E.g. `settings(inConfig(Local)(WarPlugin.projectSettings ++...`

Comment: @earldouglas Thank you! It builds .war, but doesn't apply config settings.
So, If I run Local/package command I don't have my app.properties file from src/main/local/app.properties in the artifact.

Comment: Hmm, it seems to work for me.  Do you mean `src/main/local/app.properties` or `src/main/local/resources/app.properties`?

Comment: @earldouglas I don't have `src/main/resources` directory. Just `src/main/local/resources`, `src/main/stage/resources`, `src/main/prod/resources`.
So If I run `sbt Local/package` I want to use `app.properties` file from `src/main/local/resources`, but I don't see any `app.properties` in the artifact, because it tries to get `app.properties` from `src/main/resources`, which doesn't exist.
I finally have `.war` file, but without `app.properties`, so how can I make to work `unmanagedResourceDirectories` correct?

Comment: I published the example to github:
https://github.com/eshenko/pet
maybe it helps

Comment: Thanks for the example; that helps a lot!  I think I found the problem -- we're always [pulling mappings from `Compile` configuration](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin/blob/72a564d/src/main/scala/com/earldouglas/xwp/WebappPlugin.scala#L140), regardless of which configuration we're packaging from.  I think this will have to be changed in xsbt-web-plugin itself.  I filed [a new issue](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin/issues/579) to track this.

Comment: Found workaround. My configuration is applied If I firstly run compile command then package one. So it looks like `sbt Local/compile Local/package`.